# Flex Warning: Multiple markers..Data binding will not be able to detect assignments to object

Tags: actionscript-3, flex4

I am binding an object with a label. It gives me this warning.
I have written the follwing code

s:Label width="296" height="20" fontSize="18" text="{obj.companyParty_Name}"

where companyParty_Name is a field in the obj which i want to display on the label

What does the above warning mean?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The property **companyParty_Name** is not Bindable.

[About Data Binding](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/flex/using/WS2db454920e96a9e51e63e3d11c0bf64c3d-7fff.html)

In order to make the warning go away you need to add the annotation **[Bindable]** above the property definition.  Like so:

```
[Bindable]
private var companyParty_Name:*;
```

Answer (score 1):

I had the same warning with this code

```
<mx:DateField id="buy_expiry_date" disabledRanges="{[{
    rangeEnd: new Date(today.year,today.month,today.date - 1)
}]}"/>
```

Then i changed it to

```
<mx:DateField id="buy_expiry_date" disabledRanges="{[{
    rangeEnd: new Date(today.getFullYear(),today.getMonth(),today.getDate() - 1)
}]}"/>
```

And it stopped warning me.